# Retrieve the sum of each column

Tags: sql, sum, formula

I have a table that looks like the following:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

I want to retrieve a new table with the sum of each column:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 9 | 9 | 7 |

Is there an SQL formula that allows me to do that without mentioning the name of each single column?

Comment: "*without mentioning the name of each single column*" - no.

Comment: don't be lazy SUM(A),SUM(B),SUM(C) etc.

Comment: The actual table that I have is much larger, with dozens of columns. the column names might change... sad that there is no smarter way to retrieve the sum of each column..

Comment: @SimoneRomeo . . . Columns names don't "change" in tables.  Columns are very well defined in tables and views.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the scenario and why you don't want to specify the column name, but still if you want to to you can try like following using dynamic query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_TABLE

CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE  (A INT, B INT,C INT,D INT)
INSERT INTO  TEST_TABLE SELECT 1,2,3,4
INSERT INTO  TEST_TABLE SELECT 2,2,3,4
INSERT INTO  TEST_TABLE SELECT 3,2,3,4
INSERT INTO  TEST_TABLE SELECT 2,2,3,4


DECLARE @Tablename NVARCHAR(max) = 'TEST_TABLE'

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' +  'SUM(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') AS ' +  QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    FROM sys.columns c where c.object_id = object_id(@Tablename)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') +
  + ' FROM ' + @Tablename  

EXEC (@qry)
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/TKYH43020)**